# 3d points coordinate regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have 30 sets of 3D points which are the keypoints describing 30 objects, each set contains 10 points, these points denote as X with shape [30,10,3]. I also have the corrsponding 3D points of the 30 objects after certain transformation, denote as Y with shape [30,10,3].

Now I want to train a machine learning model from these 30 objects, using the X and Y as data and annotation, and predict the keypoints coordinates of a new object after transformation.

Anybody has ideas how to do it with python?

Answer (score 0):

30 sets seem too low for the task, as the input and output have too many dimensions (30). If you need to map these high dimensional data, you need thousands of examples (more sets).

I would suggest to simulate the transformations to generate a few thousands samples. Then use a small neural network to predict the Y from X. As, the inputs don't have spatial or temporal dimensions instead represent discrete points I don't think convolutional or recurrent models will be useful.

So, start with a small MLP with mean squared error loss. However, if the output points are always integer then you can model it as a classification problem too considering the range is not big.

I have added a small neural network model in keras to predict the transformation.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape
from keras.models import Model

X = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (3000, 10, 3)) # 10 3d points
Y = 2*(X + 5)/7 # this is our simple transformation operation

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

in_m = Input(shape=(30,)) # input layer
f1_fc = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(in_m) # first fc layer
f2_fc = Dense(30, activation = 'linear')(f1_fc) # second fc layer

simple_model = Model(in_m, f2_fc)

simple_model.summary()

simple_model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mae'], optimizer='adam')


X_flat = np.reshape(X, (3000, 30))
Y_flat = np.reshape(Y, (3000, 30))

hist = simple_model.fit(X_flat, Y_flat, epochs = 100, validation_split = 0.2, batch_size = 20)
```

Output:

```
(3000, 10, 3)
(3000, 10, 3)

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)         (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 100)               3100      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 30)                3030      
=================================================================
Total params: 6,130
Trainable params: 6,130
Non-trainable params: 0
```

[image: The loss is decreasing overall. Try to experiment with new layers and hyperparameters.]